# Connect ROS with Gazebo beginner tutorial

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in ROS and Gazebo.

I'm studying robotics at the university and I need to move a robot in Gazebo using ROS. I will control the robot with the keyboard.

My problem is that I have no idea about ROS or Gazebo. I did the ROS' beginner tutorials and also some tutorials from Gazebo (the ones that talk about gazebo plugins).

I've stated reading the Gazebo: connect to ROS tutorials, but it is a mess. They talk a lot of things that I don't understand. To be more specific (the tutorials are here, http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros):

1. In Using a URDF in Gazebo, they talk to convert URDF files to Gazebo. Do I need to do that?
2. In Using Gazebo plugins with ROS, I found a question about writing a Gazebo plugin to handle a robot in Gazebo, and someone answered that we can do that using ROS. Do I need to write Gazebo plugins to connect ROS with Gazebo?
3. In ROS Control, they explain how to add transmission elements to a URDF. If I modify the URDF to use it with Gazebo, will I still using it in a ROS package?
4. I get tired to read and don't understand anything. I decided to ask here.

Reading that I think that those tutorials are for advanced users because they do thinks that I haven't do yet. I haven't modify a SDF file, I use the Gazebo's editor to modify the robot or the world.

I just need a tutorial to follow that talks about how to connect gazebo with ROS, add a robot and control it with a keyboard from ROS.

Do you know if there is something like that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291381/connect-ros-with-gazebo-beginner-tutorial/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-16**:
What exactly is it that you're having trouble with?

> They talk a lot of things that I don't understand.

Can you please be specific?

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-05-16**:
@jayess I have modified the question to be more specific. Thanks.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-16**:
Thanks. Can you also please update your question with a link to the tutorials?

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-05-16**:
Link added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have time to buy a book, chapter eight of [Programming Robots with ROS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024736.do) has exactly what you are looking for.

**edit:**

Here are responses to your specific questions.

1. You do not need to convert from URDF since ROS can spawn models in Gazebo.
2. You do not need to write Gazebo plugins since there are already some available, like [gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs)
3. Yes, you will still be using ROS.  The joints are controlled by publishing on the appropriate topics.
4. I often come here for help, too :)

---

Originally posted by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) with karma: 368 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-05-23**:
Thanks. I've read the chapter and it is very helpful, but it doen't tell how to create my own robot in Gazebo.

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-05-23**:
Check out [this link](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control) and also Chapter 16.